# Crashing application due to secondary thread trying to update UI

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, crash, thread-safety

I am using a searchbar for selecting the records from table that is populated by Sqlite DB.
Upending the table in every 120 records and reloading the table in every 200 records.
 My apps is crashing when i am dragging the table to a limit.When certain limit is covered Its crashing with error "secondary thread trying to update UI".here is the code

```
 if (indexPath.row > limit)
    {
        llimit = llimit+200 ;
        ulimit = ulimit+200 ;
           NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        [opq cancelAllOperations];
        NSLog(@"before ns operation");
        opq = [NSOperationQueue new];
        NSInvocationOperation *op = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(searchData) object:nil] autorelease];
        [opq addOperation:op];
        [pool drain];
        i++;
        limit = limit + 120 ;
    }



- (void) searchData {

    NSString *databaseName = @"imeating.sql";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDir=[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    sqlite3 *database;

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement ;
        const char *sqlStatement ;

        sqlStatement = "select category_id, upper(subitem_name), subitem_detail_id from subitem_detail where subitem_name LIKE ? order by subitem_name limit ?,?" ;
       NSLog(@"inside search b4 wildsearch %@",searchString);

        wildSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",searchString, @"%"];



        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {

            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [wildSearch UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 2, llimit);
            sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 3, ulimit);

            if (llimit <200){
                 NSLog(@"with in if limit < 200");

                itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
            }

            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init] ;

                NSString *categoryId = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                NSString *itemName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *itemId = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

                if (ulimit%200 == 0)
                {

                    [newTableView reloadData];


                }
                [pool drain];
            } 


        }
    }
```

This is happening in device only not in simulator also Lazy loading is occurring in table view . I'm am using sqllite DB (contains huge amount of data) for populating the table.
I can drag the table to a certain range of limit after then application is crashing.Crashing limit is not constant.Please help me to implement this in perfect way

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please give an Answer...I have corrected with following answer...But now lazy loading of table is happening ....i like to use show more option in table.. like apps store working....how can i put that here in my table...while loading from sqlite DB

Comment: How is your app crashing? What is the error message? How many results are being returned from your SQL query?

Comment: it showing that secondary thread trying to update UI...i am having huge amount of data in my sqlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update UI in a secondary thread, if you need to update UI then use -

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector() withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: I am sorry where i can paste this above code?                              whether                NSInvocationOperation *op = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(searchData) object:nil] autorelease]; is wrong right?

Comment: replace this NSInvocationOperation *op = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(searchData) object:nil] autorelease]; with [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(searchData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: so it will         NSInvocationOperation *op = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector() withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; this is the way?

Comment: no don't use NSInvocationOperation it is a secondary thread , use directly [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(searchData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: f (indexPath.row > limit)
    {
        llimit = llimit+200 ;
        ulimit = ulimit+200 ;
   
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        
        [opq cancelAllOperations];
  
  
        opq = [NSOperationQueue new];
  
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(searchData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        
         [opq addOperation:op]                           [pool drain];..this is correct? sorry I am beginner in iphone development

Comment: can you tel me what is the purpose of that opq and other things

Comment: if (indexPath.row > limit) { llimit = llimit+200 ; ulimit = ulimit+200 ; [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(searchData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];}

Comment: well so no need of that queue and all r8?...pool drain?

Comment: Now the table view loading is very slow...blank screen is coming when I drag fast

Comment: Can you  tell me how can I put show more option in my Table view so i can avoid this lazy loading right?

Comment: use paging in table view, means first load 10 records and add a button at 11th row then on click of this button reload table with 20 records.

Comment: how can i add paging in table view?

Comment: You can first load 10 records in an array and load your table with that array and a button "Load More" in the 11th row of table. Then on the event of this button click load 10 more records and add them to same array and call reload data to table view and add the same button to the 21st row and so on.

Comment: Is it possible use multithreading like above code and Is it possible to do some corrections on that queue to avoid secondary thread to update UI..Actually i can do dragging up to some range of limit after that only it is crashing...and still i can't do load more button method.